# Looking for Spring Security 5 OAuth2 Resource Server without Spring Boot examples, guides or resources

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring 5 MVC application without Spring Boot that I need to migrate it's current Spring Security LDAP implementatino to a new Spring Security OAuth2 Resource Server implementation. I tried for several days without any luck to convert this application to Spring Boot and I am hoping I can do this migration without Spring Boot, the problem is that all the resources I found so far (examples,guides,etc.) only work with Spring Boot.
Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.